# How to inject some algorithm into BizForm Input / Output?

Tags: c#, kentico

I am making some modification about BizForm data input / output. How do I setup or configure for this ?

In Kentico 10, there is a BizForm, and it contains user credit card info such as card number, token, and cvc, cardholder name, etc.
Just now, all of these info are stored into database, but anyone who access to database can see them.
I made some custom module for BizFormItem insertAtrer, encrypted them and stored into database.
Now, from the Kentico Admin's Forms application, only can see encrypted data, but I want to see decrypted info in admin panel.

```
    private void BizFormItem_InsertAfterHandler(object sender, BizFormItemEventArgs e)
        {
            BizFormItem formDataItem = e.Item;

            if (formDataItem != null && formDataItem.BizFormClassName == "bizform.of2")
            {
                string CardNumber = formDataItem.GetStringValue("CAR", "");
                if(CardNumber.Substring(0,2) != "XX")
                {
                    CardNumber = "XX" + WWCipherProvider.Encrypt(CardNumber, "XXXXXXXXX");
                }

                formDataItem.SetValue("CAR", CardNumber);
                formDataItem.SubmitChanges(false);
            }
        }
```

I want to see decrypted info using WWCipherProvider.Decrypt function in Forms application Recorded data tab.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing your work on the InsertAfter event.  So this means you'd need to do an update to your data after it's inserted.  I'd suggest using the InsertBefore event.  This way you can capture the data before the insert happens and perform the "transformation" on it then.

Comment: The problem was in the decryption of encrypted form data.